# Dynamic file path in System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

How do you pass a dynamic file path in `System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable()`, I have tried folder1/folder2/file.json and it is not working, it seems like I need the 'C://' in order to execute it.

is there a way to have a dynamic file path?

Comment: When you say "dynamic", do you mean "relative"? The environment variable does not care about its content, so was does "it is not working" and "in order to execute it" mean?

Comment: Or do you specifically mean the environment variable "PATH"?

Comment: This question would be much clearer if you included the code that you have tried.